# Putting column names from database table into a list

Tags: database, vb.net, list, variables, ms-access

I am trying to put columns names from a table inside a Microsoft Access database inside a list variable. I have done this so far but the line where I am trying to add it to the topic variable does not work and is coming up with the error

> predefined type ‘valuetuple(of,,,)’ is not defined or imported.

The code is:

```
Dim topic = topic()
Dim filtervalues = {Nothing, Nothing, "Results", Nothing}
Dim counter As Integer = 0
Using con = _
    New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb")
    Dim columns = con.GetSchema("columns", filtervalues)

    For Each row As DataRow In columns.Rows
        topic(counter) = ("{0,-20}{1}", row("column_name"), row("data_type"))
        counter = +1
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to increment `counter` rather than set it to 1 then you need `counter += 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation on [Value Tupels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/tuples) you must get the NuGet package System.ValueTuple, if you are working with Framework version prior to 4.7:

> **Important**
>
> Tuple support requires the ValueTuple type. If the .NET Framework 4.7 is not installed, you must add the NuGet package System.ValueTuple, which is available on the NuGet Gallery. Without this package, you may get a compilation error similar to, "Predefined type 'ValueTuple(Of,,,)' is not defined or imported."

In Visual Studio 2017 right click on your solution and select "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...". In the search-box enter "valuetuple". Select "System.ValueTuple" and on the right click the check boxes of the projects where you want to install the package and click Install.

See: [NuGet Package Manager UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui)

Also, you must declare the list variable as

```
Dim topic = New List(Of (String, String, String))
```

and add new elements with

```
topic.Add(("{0,-20}{1}", row("column_name"), row("data_type")))
```

The counter is not needed anymore.

---

Alternatively, you could use a list of strings and format the string with string interpolation

```
Dim topic = New List(Of String)
Dim filtervalues = {Nothing, Nothing, "Results", Nothing}
Using con =
    New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb")
    Dim columns = con.GetSchema("columns", filtervalues)

    For Each row As DataRow In columns.Rows
        topic.Add($"{row("column_name"),-20}{row("data_type")}")
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: thank you, it fixed the issue. You were a really big help

Comment: I have used the second block of code you recommended for strings, however i am now using a search piece of code to find the index of one of the column names, but it comes up -1. I am using  'Dim indexOfMyTopic = topic.FindIndex(Function(topics) (mytopic.Equals(topics)))'. Do you know what the issue is

Comment: It should be something like `Dim indexOfMyTopic = topic.FindIndex(Function(s) s = mytopic)` where s represents a string entry. But since you also have a type name, maybe you want `Dim indexOfMyTopic = topic.FindIndex(Function(s) s.StartsWith(mytopic))`

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the `"{0,-20}{1}"`, you forgot the `String.Format` in

```
topic(counter) = String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", row("column_name"), row("data_type"))
```

and did not intend to use a tuple.

Comment: Yes, probably. But the `topic` variable does still not work. An array is not ideal as the number of entries is not known in advance, so probably a `List(Of String)` in conjunction with `Add(...)` instead of `counter` is best .

Comment: *I* know that. *You* know that. Let's wait for the OP to ask a new question :)